What is this movie series? Action, thriller, spy-ish genre?
There's a series of movies, action-based thriller genre. Kind of spy-ish, was released fairly recently (no earlier than 2010, I think, and even that's pushing it).
The description for this movie (I think it was the third movie of the series) was basically a girl in a science lab and then some people come in and they seem cool at first but then they're not so cool and they try to shoot this girl, but then the main character comes in and he saves the girl and then they have to go to another country, I think they had to go to China? And so they go to China to do spy stuff and there's a really cool motorcycle chase, and that's basically the most I remember from the movie. 
I know that the series was the type of series where the main title stays the same but the subtitle is always different, like Harry Potter: Prisoner of Azkaban; Harry Potter: Goblet of Fire. I don't remember the name of this movie! Can anyone help?

It's The Bourne Legacy. The movie contains  everything you described

An expansion of the universe from Robert Ludlum's novels, centered on a new hero whose stakes have been triggered by the events of the previous three films. 

From Wikipedia 


Dr. Donald Foite, a researcher at a bio-genetics laboratory, shoots and kills all but one of his top-level colleagues employed by Outcome.
leaving biochemist Dr. Marta Shearing (Rachel Weisz) as the sole survivor
four elite assassins ambush Marta at her country house.
Aaron and Marta travel to Manila, where the chems are manufactured, to try to infect him with another virus so he will not need the blue chems.





The lab scene
You can see parts of the house scene and the motorcycle chase in this video 



